# Singleton in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton

I would like to collect more variants for create singleton class.
Could you please provide to me the best creation way in C# by your opinion.

Thanks.

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    Singleton _instance = null;

    public Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(_instance == null)
                _instance = new Singleton();

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    // Default private constructor so only we can instanctiate
    private Singleton() { }

    // Default private static constructor
    private static Singleton() { }
}
```

Comment: Mmh... sounds like already asked...

Comment: @Klaus: This implementation is *not* fine... the property and fields are non-static... how could you ever create an instance?

Comment: @Jon, right, `Instance` should be static. Didn't notice that. Will edit my post.

Comment: If I create a singleton, which is rare as I want to have very testable code, then I use Lazy<T> to create the instance now. You get thread safety, lazy initialization, and short concise code. But in general, avoid singletons, because they are EVIL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have an [entire article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) on this which you may find useful.

Oh, and try to avoid using the singleton pattern in general, due to its pain for testability etc :)

Comment: Haha, Jon, obviously, your article is well known ;-) Three answers in a few seconds with the same article.

Comment: great, I have been following your article and implementing versions 4 and 5 sometimes. Fully agree Singleton should be avoided unless really, really required.

Answer (score 0):

look here : http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    static readonly Singleton instance=new Singleton();

    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
    // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
    static Singleton()
    {
    }

    Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that that's the old URL - the updated version on csharpindepth.com is where any changes will end up.