# Singleton implementation

Tags: c#, .net, singleton

I wrote a piece of code about singleton pattern implementation. Not sure its correctness. Please give some advice. Thanks.

```
public class Singleton
{
    public Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                if (_mutexCreation.WaitOne(0))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (_instance == null)
                        {
                            _instance = new Singleton();
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        _mutexCreation.ReleaseMutex();
                        _eventCreation.Set();
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    _eventCreation.WaitOne();
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private Singleton() { }

    private static Singleton _instance;
    private static Mutex _mutexCreation = new Mutex();
    private static ManualResetEvent _eventCreation = new ManualResetEvent(false);
}
```

Comment: Please tag this with whatever language this is, so it'll catch experts from that community. :)

Comment: here's some advice regarding singletons: *just don't use them*: http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040986/singleton-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static object _syncRoot = new object();

    public Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                lock (_syncRoot)
                {
                    if (_instance != null)
                       return _instance;

                    _instance = new Singleton();
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private Singleton() { }
    private static Singleton _instance;
}
```

If you do not want to use lazy loading, simply create a new instance directly in a static constructor.

Comment: thanks, i know, i want to be lazy. i am thinking about if this could be more efficient than the traditional double check implementation using mutex (or critical region).

Comment: Do not do premature optimizations. imho this code is more readable and therefore better.

Comment: Let me elaborate further. Lazy loading usually means that the object either consumes a lot of resources or takes some CPU to load. In contrast to that it doesn't really matter how much time the locking mechanism takes.

Comment: you're right, this is a trade-off thing. thanks.

Comment: i was considering if there are MANY asynchronous calls to the Instance property before the _instance got initialized, my code could be more efficient. right?

Comment: The creation (and the lock) is only invoked once per thread during the application lifetime. So your code is more effective if the applications life time is **very** short.

Comment: thanks very much. learned a lot!